# Getting the nr. of rows in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm faced with a little problem, I want to count the total number of rows from a db table.
I try this queries, but with no success:

```
$nr = mysql_query("select [TotalCount]=rows from $tablename where ID=object_ID('gyuruszam')");

$nr = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(gyuruszam) FROM $tablename");

$nr = mysql_query("SELECT gyuruszam FROM $tablename, st.row_count");
```

Please help me out on this, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a handle to the result, not the result itself. See PHP docs.

Comment: don't use mysql_* functions they are deprecated use PDO or mysqli

Comment: Also, grab phpMyAdmin, or just http://SQLFiddle.com, and check your SQL queries before trying to integrate them in PHP if you're not familiar with how they work (no idea what that first query is supposed to be...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Try This:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename"));
```

Comment: This will work, but be incredibly inefficient, since the entire content of the table must be passed from MySQL to PHP. Using COUNT(*) on the DB lets MySQL tell you the answer without even looking at what the table contains.

Comment: yes, it's working, sorry for missunderstanding the code.. thank you very much!
I supplemented a little the query, like this:
`$rowcount =  mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT gyuruszam FROM $tablename"));`

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the result of the `COUNT` a name using `AS`, e.g., `numrows`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(gyuruszam) as numrows from $tablename");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['numrows'];
```

Comment: if `gyuruszam` is null, it doesn't count that `null` valued row

Answer (score 2):

```
query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $tablename)
```

When using `*`, it includes possible `null` values. When using `COUNT(gyuruszam)` and `gyuruszam` contains null, those rows won't get counted.

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `PDO` or at least `mysqli` instead.

Personally I suggest not to put a variable straight into a quoted string as it may lead to unexpected behaviour in some situations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence; in your example, you use `"some stuff " . $variable`; since you're using double quotes anyway, there's absolutely no difference between that and `"some stuff $variable"`.

Comment: @IMSoP It's way cleaner coding style not to put variables into quoted strings. What do you expect here: `$a = 'a'; $aa = 'b'; echo "$aaa$a$aa";` its dirty code style. The stackoverflow code highlighting also shows that.

Comment: I expect it to look up a variable called $aaa, because variables aren't limited to one letter in PHP. I grant that it *can* be ambiguous, and respect that you consider it bad style, but I don't think a blanket ban on using it, with no explanation, is particularly relevant or useful in this answer.

Comment: @IMSoP I can agree with your last comment and modified my answer to make it more clear it's not something strict.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the number of rows in a table use **[mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)**

Also **mysql_*** are deprecated from **MySQL 5.5**

[Take few minutes to read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: That will echo 1: the result of the query is one row containing a number.

Comment: Thanks for pointout my mistake. I just copied and paste it directly. I edited now

Comment: The count(*) version will be much more efficient than fetching all the rows into PHP, you just needed to output the result, not the size of the result.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount FROM $tablename")` this should return an integer with number of records in $tablename

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount FROM $tablename");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['totalCount'];
```